# ESP8266 Programming using ESP-01 to USB converter

Tags: esp8266, uart, programmer, ch340

I am new to ESP8266. To ease out the task of programming esp8266, I bought this:  [ESP-01 ESP8266 Programmer CH340G Chip USB WiFi Wireless UART GPIO0 Adapter](http://www.ebay.in/itm/ESP-01-ESP8266-Programmer-CH340G-Chip-USB-WiFi-Wireless-UART-GPIO0-Adapter-/272370382534?).

[image: ESP-01 to USB converter Connected]

Configured Arduino Interface to run **AT** commands in the serial monitor.
I flashed ESP8266 with the basic **blink LED** example. It worked fine for some time and later on gave this error.

```
warning: espcomm_sync failed
```

When i tried to flash another program on to ESP8266, I am getting the following error.

```
Sketch uses 221,995 bytes (51%) of program storage space. Maximum is 434,160 bytes.
Global variables use 31,568 bytes (38%) of dynamic memory, leaving 50,352 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81,920 bytes.
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
error: failed reading byte
warning: espcomm_send_command: cant receive slip payload data
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

I could only find [one article](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=all-in-one-esp-usb-converter) regarding this adapter. 
There he made a custom bridge soldering GPIO 0 to GND for ESP8266 Flashing.

So should i make a removable bridge for the same, to upload a new program.
Is there any other way to simplify this task?

Comment: Thank you for the post you made! You should auto-answer this post with the post link "Check how to solve it [here]" and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I have this exact same module and what really puzzles me is that someone designed and manufactured this product, which simply does not work as advertised.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I just recently tried to use this adapter myself and ran into the same issue. I was able to modify the adapter to use it for flashing the ESP-01.. For all of you still looking for answer, I've written instructable here https://www.instructables.com/id/USB-to-ESP-01-Board-Adapter-Modification/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I made a breadboard connection joining ESP8266's GPIO 0 and GND to Programmer's GND for flashing the chip

[For more info](http://www.arjunsk.com/iot/programming-esp8266-esp-01-using-esp8266-programmer-ch340g-chip-adapter/)

[image: Connections]

Additional Reference:
[Programming ESP8266](http://www.arjunsk.com/tag/esp8266/)

Comment: Many thanks, you saved me a lot of time! Btw an even simpler way would be fitting a small copper wire plugged in gnd and gpio-0 and then putting the esp01 on top of it

Answer (score 0):

Just solder a jumper to the adapter according to this image (bottom side):
[image: esp-01 adapter]

If you want to use programming mode, just switch to connect GND and GPIO0. Switch back to use GPIO0 as IO pin (you may attach your F-F Dupont cable to the floating pin).